# ios6.0.1 recvfrom always blocks on iphone

Tags: sockets, ios6, udp

We created a iOS app which performs UDP send operation (send request to server) in a thread (we use bsd socket API), another thread performs UDP receive operation (receive response from server) on the same socket.

It works correctly on iOS 4/5, but when we tested it on iOS 6.0.1 (iPhone) it does not work, no problem found on iPad with iOS 6.0.1 and simulator.

The app blocked on `recvfrom` infinitely, we are sure there is UDP response from server. 
It seems that it's the same problem as this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cocoaasyncsocket/rWokj2VO3VE/f-mZ6xWEUhkJ.

Code snippet:

```
char recvData[UDP_PACKAGE_LENGTH];
bzero(recvData, UDP_PACKAGE_LENGTH);
struct sockaddr_in fromAddr;
uint32_t len = sizeof(fromAddr);
int isHead = recvfrom(self->serverSock, recvData, UDP_PACKAGE_LENGTH, 0, (struct sockaddr*)(&fromAddr), &len);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a guess - are there any new firewalling services/policies in iOS 6.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

Bug is be found! We did not receive UDP packets from Cellular, but TCP is passable ,so that the recvfrom block infinitely.